How can I remove unpermitted intrinsics?
I am working on a React/js/vite project and I stumbled upon this error:
X [ERROR] Two output files share the same path but have different contents: 
node_modules\.vite\deps_temp_eeee2960\react.js

The error above occurs in my terminal. The error below occurs in my chrome console:
Removing unpermitted intrinsics
client:556 [vite] server connection lost. Polling for restart...
:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-dom_client.js?v=edb49463:1 
        
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESETUnderstand this errorAI
:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=1f4580c2:1 
        
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I expect to get the server running back after resolving this. I have deleted my node modules, package.json, changed the port, and also cleared my cache, but nothing is working.
